# how to do anonymous vector in R?

Tags: r

I can do this to get the even numbers from 1 to 10

```
x <- 1:10
x[x %% 2 == 0]
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

but I want to do it without the x.
I want to do something like:

```
1:10[_ %% 2 == 0]
```

is there syntax for this?

Comment: Use the parentheses i.e. `(1:10)[(1:10) %% 2 == 0]` as there is a precedence for operators.

Comment: thanks, if you make it an answer I'll mark it accepted

Comment: I like that even better

Comment: Error: could not find function "%>%"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `%>%`

```
library(magrittr)
1:10 %>% subset(.%% 2 == 0)
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```